# Обмен сигналами между потоками

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Запускаются два потока. Потокам на выполнение даётся одна и та же функция. Функция работы потока выглядит следующим образом: выполняется некое вычисление, затем поток смотрит, закончил ли вычисления 2ой поток. Если не закончил, то поток ложиться спать и просыпается, когда закончит вычисления 2ой поток. Ниже вычисления имитируются при помощи метода sleep()

```
void func(int time) {
   this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(time)); //имитация вычислений

   if(второй поток не закончил вычисления)
      этот поток засыпает и просыпается, когда второй поток закончит 
      вычисления
}

int main() {
   thread th1(func, 10);
   thread th2(func, 50);
   th1.join();
   th2.join();
   return 0;
}
```

Я думал про условную переменную, но, насколько я понимаю, для этого нужно что-бы потоки запускали разные функции, а в примере выше оба запускают одну и ту же функцию func(). Если какой-то способ, как в pthread например, где есть обмен сигналами между потоками без условных переменных

Comment: Почему просто не подождать th2.join() ?  (адрес второго потока можно передать дополнительным аргументом функции, или через глобальную прееменную.

Comment: Для этого существует `OpenMP` например, там все предусмотрено, и потоки просто так не простаивают.

Comment: @Chorkov, в таком случае легче поменять местами `th2.join() ` и `th1.join() `  :)

Comment: @Chorkov как передать адрес потока параметром?

Comment: @zhukov `void func(int time, thread* wait_for=nullptr){ ... if(wait_for)wait_for->join()`  `thread th1(func, 50, &th2);`